# Square API, listener for products sold by card reader

Tags: javascript, python, square-connect

I am trying to create a Kitchen Display System using square (like Fresh KDS), I would like my server to be able to listen to when an order goes through. For instance, when an order happens and the customer orders a coffee and an ice cream I would like an independent server to get those items. I tried looking at the Square API, especially the Point of Sale API, but that wants the card reader to handle callbacks. I would prefer if the Server was independent and only listened for when an order was successful, and could extract the items purchased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square supports [webhooks](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/webhooks), which should do what you want if you subscribe to the `PAYMENT_UPDATED` event.

In the event the webhook doesn't return all the data you need, it does return an ID for the transaction, which your webhook listener can use to look up the required information using the API.

Comment: Hey, Im finally trying this. The webhook returns the following:
{"entity_id":"hR3HaEWlSWAvY6CM6aI4KQB","event_type":"PAYMENT_UPDATED","merchant_id":"YYYYYYYYYYYYY","location_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}

What ID do I use in order to get information of the purchase. Do I use the transactions API, because I initially tried using the connect v1 item management, but it seems that a transaction of a payment is different than the items.

Comment: @HarounAnsari Looks from the docs like it's the entity ID and the transactions API.

Comment: I am trying to get the name of an item based on the v1 items API, however there seems to be no simple link for entity_id -> item name.

From the entity_id you can get a transaction based upon looking at the tenders of your transactions and checking which one matches your entity_id. However, there is nothing that you can get from the transaction to then search your item and find its name. There should be a much simpler way to get an item and its name based on values obtained from a webhook, but I cant seem to find anyway.

Comment: Figured it out through using the payments API